# How to extend storage in Openshift?

Tags: openshift

Openshift container platform contains `Storage` section where we can manage list of available storages. Editing storages however is not possible using UI. The only action available is delete. The documentation available [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/architecture/additional_concepts/storage.html) doesn't describe the simple operation of expanding the storage.

How to expand the storage in Openshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you create your StorageClass with `allowVolumeExpansion: true` ? If you want to expand existing PV/PVC, you need to use PV/PVC through StorageClass. Refer here : [Enabling Expansion of Persistent Volume Claims](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expanding_persistent_volumes.html#enabling_expansion_pvc) for more details.

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard-testing
:
```

Comment: First of all thank you. It seems good way. However - do you know if it's possible to do it without touching storage class definition? Unfortunately due to permission/policy I can't edit it.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have not cluster-admin or storage-admin role to configure "allowVolumeExpansion: true" with new storageclass, AFAIK there is no  way to expand a PV/PVC. You may create bigger PVC again after remove an existing PVC.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not able to adjust the StorageClass to specify `allowVolumeExpansion: true`, your only other option is to create a new, larger PV, and migrate the data.

This can potentially be automated with a script. Assuming only RWO volumes are available, this will require some minimal downtime, since the volume can only be attached to one volume at a time.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# usage: script.sh <deploymentconfig-name> <pvc-claim-name> <volume-name-on-deployment> <desired-pvc-size>
# example: script.sh postgresql postgresql postgresql-data 5Gi

set -e

DEPLOYMENT="$1"
PVCCLAIMNAME="$2"
DEPLOYMENTVOLUMENAME="$3"
PVCSIZE="$4"

RANDOM_ID=$(uuidgen | awk -F- '{ print tolower($2) }')

oc run pv-migration --image=registry.redhat.io/rhel7/rhel-tools --replicas=0 -- tail -f /dev/null
oc set volume deploymentconfig pv-migration --add -t pvc --name=old-pv --claim-name=$PVCCLAIMNAME --mount-path=/old-pv-path
oc set volume deploymentconfig pv-migration --add -t pvc --name=new-pv --claim-name=${PVCCLAIMNAME}${RANDOM_ID} --mount-path=/new-pv-path --claim-mode=ReadWriteOnce --claim-size=$PVCSIZE
oc scale deploymentconfig $DEPLOYMENT --replicas=0
oc scale deploymentconfig pv-migration --replicas=1

# Wait for pod
while [[ -z $(oc get pods -l deploymentconfig=pv-migration -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase=="Running")].metadata.name}' | cut -d " " -f 1) ]]
do
    echo Waiting for "pv-migration" pod
    sleep 1
done

oc exec $(oc get pods -l deploymentconfig=pv-migration -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase=="Running")].metadata.name}' | cut -d " " -f 1) -- rsync -avxHAX --no-t --progress /old-pv-path/ /new-pv-path/
oc delete deploymentconfig pv-migration --grace-period=0 --force
oc set volume deploymentconfig $DEPLOYMENT --add --name=$DEPLOYMENTVOLUMENAME --claim-name=${PVCCLAIMNAME}${RANDOM_ID} --overwrite
oc scale deploymentconfig $DEPLOYMENT --replicas=1

echo Done
```

There is a community guide with this and more information published at https://github.com/openshift-cs/OpenShift-Troubleshooting-Templates/blob/master/resize.md